# My 8 yr old staffie has a weeping rash on his legs and really bad under his penis

Tags: dogs

My dog has a rash on his underside and he’s crying in pain, he’s letting me touch it with a wet tissue (seems to relieve the pain).

I can’t get to the vet how can I help him?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Likely a yeast infection he exacerbated by licking. Fungal infections can be difficult to tame but it is possible. Firstly, he needs a cone to stop him from
licking the affected area.  An needs anti-fungal cream is indicated:    Chlotrimazole
    •   Econazole
    •   Itraconazole
    •   Ketoconazole (has antibacterial effects as well)
    •   Miconazole

Try an anti-fungal to start as to avoid a vet visit. If no improvement within 48 hrs, vet visit is indicated.

If there is discharge from the penis, flushing may also be required.

Good luck, let us know the outcome.

Comment: Thank you   it’s stoped weeping over night and it looks a lot better and a lot less red but I’m going to take him to a vet tomorrow as he gets this rash a lot just not as bad as last night

Comment: Let us know please what the vet has to say. Glad he’s feeling better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fungal infection. Flush the area with 0.9% normal saline and apply a topical solution of 0.8% ketoconazole. If symptoms continue over the dedicated period for treatment of 48 hours consult with a dermatologist.

Comment: You duplicated my answer.

Comment: no I did not. I referred the manuals at unity veterinary practice. But I doubted most humans would process 'Flush the area with 0.9% normal saline and apply a topical solution of 0.8% ketoconazole. If symptoms continue over the dedicated period for treatment of 48 hours  consult with a demitoloist